# In shopify, how can I align the "size-option" variations of my products to the quantity boxes that are below?

Tags: css, shopify, selection

I'm trying to use CSS in Shopify to customise a specific product; the layout/arrangement of the class "size-option" variations, they come in age ranges, and therefore the text field is shorter than the quantity box below and they don't line up (compared to small, medium, large, x-large where they naturally line up ok).

[View of issue without CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpUML.png)

I am having issues with the CSS where I cannot select the individual product as parent of the color-option class.

I have tried applying a text-align: justify as an initial rule to make the text span the width of the space available, but that didn't work as intended... Nothing happened.

So I decided to attempt to use the padding and margin. I've found that this worked pretty well, not perfect but good enough to pass my needs. However this code applied to the whole sites product pages, and is currently unusable for my needs as I want it to only select either the product classes I say, or to a product tag (if possible)

My attempt to do this is as follows:

```
.product-8029862002921,
.color-option,
span {
  text-align: justify;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.product-8029862002921,
.color-option {
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.three-eighths {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
.color-box-wrapper {
  width: 75px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

I presume the use of commas isn't being used correct here, as I want to apply the first style rules to the spans of color option as a child of product-802986'. Shopify shows an error, that there are no span in color-option when I remove the commas from the css, but there definitely is, as seen when inspecting this in browser it shows the size variations in the colour option div as spans. See below code

```
<div class="bulk-order">
  
  <div class="size-option">
    
    <span> 1-2 </span>    
    
    <span> 3-4 </span>    
    
    <span> 5-6 </span>    
    
    <span> 7-8 </span>    
    
    <span> 9-11 </span>    
    
    <span> 12-13 </span>    
    
    <span> 14-15 </span>    
    
  </div>
```

Ideally I want to create a code that selects the product and color-option span to widen the gap between the sizes, and then I was adding margins to align them with the table of quanitity boxes below. then adding another margin the the column to bring it back to where it was before the margin of -value before.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Not clear, what try to do

Comment: 1-2, 3-4, 5-6,etc align with the boxes below.
When use code it applies changes to every product page. 
Only want changes to products that have ages as size (using class of product-ID/tag)

this code:
}.product-8029862002921 .color-option
span {
  text-align: justify;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 14px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

returns
Invalid custom CSS only single selectors comma-separated selector-lists or combinator selectors are supported.